# Why moving the OAK repo to MongoDB is a challenge for the Publish instance of AEM

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

As we have seen that Adobe Experience Manager comes with a bundled installer for the JCR and it keeps the Content Repository along with the Framework and it is doesn't provide option to decouple the content repo from the CMS framework by allowing it to shift it to a DB like MongoDB.
It's possible only for Author instance whereas I haven't seen that recommended for Publish instance.
Can someone please explain why is it difficult to decouple the framework from the repo ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use mongo with author or publish. Author and publish are identical in terms of tech-stack and i dont see why using mongo will be more difficult with a publish instance. Please be more specific on the challenges you are having.

Comment: Monogo DB is just a persistence layer, even with mongo DB as the persistence layer you are still using JCR and there is no way to separate AEM from JCR.

Comment: More than a challenge, it is the benefit you could get from it, since the publish instances are distributed and synchronized by design. That is not the case if you need to have more than one author instance and you need to ensure the same content across the authoring instances.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, please go through this link from adobe, it explicitley says to use MongoDB with Author - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/aem-with-mongodb.html
Do you have any reference link which explains to configure AEM with Mongo or any other external data source for a publish instance ?

Comment: @ronnyfm, can you pls simplify your answer, If I configure an external datasource (JCR) for AEM publish instances, will it add any value in terms of performance ?

Comment: @RahulMohan Oh, but that is different, and you do not need Mongo for that. Indeed you can use a shared datasource and use binary-less replication. The gain is mostly in replication times: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/data-store-config.html

Regarding the publish instance performance rendering the pages, there should not be much impact, since AEM does have a local cache in order to not fetch from the shared datastore continually